# How to automatically call some code before and after the main code of a method?

Tags: java

I am trying to put some code before and after the main code of a method but I don't know how to it generically?

```
public class A extends Subject {
    private int attribute1;
    private int attribute2;

    public A (int attribute1, int attribute2) {
        super();
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
    }

    public A copy(){...}

    public void setAttribute1(int attribute1) {
        A childBefore = this.copy(); // want it to be generic
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.notify(childBefore, this); // want it to be generic
    }

    public void setAttribute2(int attribute2) {
        A childBefore = this.copy(); // want it to be generic
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
        this.notify(childBefore, this); // want it to be generic
    }
}
```

So basically, I don't want `the initialization and the notify part` to be defined in each method which need to. I've found one possible solution which consists in define this in a parent class and call `Child childBefore = super.before()` and `super.after()`. But it's still repetition, does anyone knows how to make it as much generics as possible?

Comment: You can create an object of that Master class and use the object to call the method..

Comment: To call the setters of `Child` you need to create an instance of `Child`. If you don't know at runtime what `Child` actually is, you need to find all the subclasses of `Master`. The [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library might be helpful for that.

Comment: Have you tried reflection?

Comment: The reflection will give you what you want (as long as the instance is of Child type), but this seems like asking for trouble - someone can in the future create method called "setupConnection" with different signature, and the whole thing will crash.

I think that the proper pattern would be just to have an abstract method in Parent, like 'callSetters' and force every child to implement it with explicit calls to setX, setY etc.

Comment: How would you invoke a bunch of methods without having the correct parameters to feed the methods? And what are you trying to achieve in the long run - I have the feeling you're making it way too complicated and error prone.

Comment: a) It is possible b) The fundamental issue with using reflection is is presumably you don't "know" about these methods at compile time. So how are you going to know how to pass valid parameters to the setters?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But we don't define the children methods so we don't know which one we need to call.

Comment: Sorry guys, i didn't explain my need correctly, i made some changes, could you look at it?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base
{
public void foo()
{
    doStuff();
}
public void doStuff()
{
    print("base");
}
}
```

class Derived extends Base
    {
        @Override
        public void doStuff()
        {
            print("derived");
        }
    }

```
new Derived().foo(); // Prints "derived".
```

Obviously all of Derived's methods have to be already defined in Base, but to do it otherwise (without introspection) would be logically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

To do it reflectively, you would have to do something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child child = new Child(0, 0);
    Class<Child> childClass = child.getClass();
    for (Method method : childClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
            method.invoke(child, new Object[] { });
        }
    }
}
```

But you may need to provide additional checking on the method name, in order to invoke it correctly.